# Coffeescript function declaration func: -> or func = ->?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm reading through the spine.js documentation and I'm wondering a little bit about the function declarations.
In the doc i always read

```
constructor: ->
  super
  ....
```

But otherwise i always read

```
constructor = ->
  super
  ....
```

So are : and = equal for function declarations?

Comment: What does the compiled javascript look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

When defining a class, the `:` works slightly differently than it does elsewhere.  In a class definition the `:` means to put this function as a method on the prototype (instance method).  `constructor:` is a special case to be used for the constructor function.

The difference is obvious if you look at the compiled javascript.

```
class Foo
  constructor: -> @foo = 'foo'
  method: ->
```

compiles to this (Good!)

```
var Foo;
Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
  }
  Foo.prototype.method = function() {};
  return Foo;
})();
```

You can see the constructor is the constructor, and the method is on the prototype.

However, when you use `=` you simply assign local variables and the functions are not really part of the class as the constructor or the prototype:

```
class Bar
  constructor = -> @bar = 'bar'
  method = ->
```

Compiles to this (Bad!)

```
var Bar;
Bar = (function() {
  var constructor, method;
  function Bar() {}
  constructor = function() {
    return this.bar = 'bar';
  };
  method = function() {};
  return Bar;
})();
```

Many issues about coffee script syntax can be discovered or resolved by simply looking at the compiled result.  And this also why I do not recommend learning coffee script without also knowing JavaScript, as some of the things that it does for don't really make sense if you dont know what it compiles into.

Comment: +1 for "Many issues about coffee script syntax can be discovered or resolved by simply looking at the compiled result.". If you hit any kind of error, look at the compiled result. Especially for syntax errors like "unexpected indent" it is really useful to have a browser window open with the "Try it" page where you can just paste snippets in and get immediate feedback.

Comment: It's worth noting that, before 0.9.0, `x = y` and `x: y` were synonymous in CoffeeScript. Today, of course, `x: y` means `{x: y}`.